# .htaccess redirect urls containing dynamic segments

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm working on a site that does phone number lookups and stores them to a mysql database. The site has a three-page drill-down method to look for a phone number. So the process in order is:

1. `phone-number/areacode.php?a=aaa`
2. `phone-number/prefix.php?a=aaa&b=bbb`
3. `phone-number/number.php?a=aaa&b=bbb&c=cccc`

`areacode.php` simply shows a listing of all area codes in the system. `prefix.php` simply shows a listing of all area codes along with relative prefixes in the system.

Currently (for SEO purposes) we have these three pages rewriting to the following (in respective order as above):

1. `phone-number/aaa`
2. `phone-number/aaa/bbb`
3. `phone-number/aaa/bbb/cccc`

I don't know why the previous developer used slashes but again for SEO purposes we want to change the `slashes` to `dashes` while performing 301 redirects. The end result would look like:

1. `phone-number/aaa`
2. `phone-number/aaa-bbb`
3. `phone-number/aaa-bbb-cccc`

Here is the current code being used for this in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule phone-number/([0-9]{3})/([0-9]{3})/([0-9]{4}) /phone-number/number.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3
RewriteRule phone-number/([0-9]{3})/([0-9]{3}) /phone-number/prefix.php?a=$1&b=$2
RewriteRule phone-number/([0-9]{3}) /phone-number/areacode.php?a=$1
```

I don't know where to begin to 301 redirect these dynamic URL's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have code like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# convert / to -
RewriteRule ^(phone-number)/([0-9]{3})/([0-9]{3})/([0-9]{4})/?$ /$1/$2-$3-$4 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(phone-number)/([0-9]{3})/([0-9]{3})/?$ /$1/$2-$3 [L,R=301]

# rewrite to php handler
RewriteRule ^phone-number/([0-9]{3})-([0-9]{3})-([0-9]{4})/?$ /phone-number/number.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^phone-number/([0-9]{3})-([0-9]{3})/?$ /phone-number/prefix.php?a=$1&b=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^phone-number/([0-9]{3})/?$ /phone-number/areacode.php?a=$1 [L,QSA]
```